# Check and update localStorage if user re-opens the browser on system/browser crash in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to update the values of a list stored in `localStorage` based on the values of `sessionStorage` and `window` object of each tab.
I have different scenarios here:

1. User starts a new process in each tab.
2. Refreshes/closes a tab
3. Browser is closed
4. System crashes - browser close button is not clicked here. This is direct shut down

I have written the code as below. This code updates the values in all the storages for the first two cases mentioned above. But it does not update in the third and fourth cases. What changes can I make to make this work?

```
const data = useRef('');

const setDatatInLocalStorage = (event?) => {
  if (!event) {
    event = window.event;
  }
  if (event.key == 'dataList') {
    const localStorageDataList = JSON.parse(event.newValue || '[]');
    localStorage.setItem('dataList', JSON.stringify(localStorageDataList));
  }
};

window.addEventListener('storage', setDatatInLocalStorage, {
  once: true,
});

window.onbeforeunload = function () {
  const sessionStorageDataList = JSON.parse(
    sessionStorage.getItem('dataList') || '[]',
  );
  if (sessionStorageDataList.length > 0) {
    let localStorageDataList = JSON.parse(
      localStorage.getItem('dataList') || '[]',
    );
    if (localStorageDataList.length > 0) {
      localStorageDataList = localStorageDataList.filter(
        (data) => !sessionStorageDataList.includes(data),
      );
      localStorage.setItem('dataList', JSON.stringify(localStorageDataList));
    }
  }
  sessionStorage.removeItem('dataList');
};

window.onload = function () {
  const sessionStorageDataList = JSON.parse(
    sessionStorage.getItem('dataList') || '[]',
  );
  if (sessionStorageDataList.length > 0) {
    let localStorageDataList = JSON.parse(
      localStorage.getItem('dataList') || '[]',
    );
    if (localStorageDataList.length > 0) {
      localStorageDataList = localStorageDataList.filter(
        (data) => !sessionStorageDataList.includes(data),
      );
      localStorage.setItem('dataList', JSON.stringify(localStorageDataList));
    }
  }
  sessionStorage.removeItem('dataList');
};

const updatedataList = (data) => {
  if ((window as any).dataList) {
    (window as any).dataList.push(data);
  } else {
    (window as any).dataList = [data];
  }
  sessionStorage.setItem(
    'dataList',
    JSON.stringify((window as any).dataList),
  );
  if (
    'dataList' in localStorage &&
    !isEmpty(localStorage.getItem('dataList'))
  ) {
    const localStorageDataList = JSON.parse(
      localStorage.getItem('dataList') || '[]',
    );
    localStorageDataList.push(data);
    localStorage.setItem('dataList', JSON.stringify(localStorageDataList));
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem('dataList', JSON.stringify([data]));
  }
};

const removedataList = () => {
  if ((window as any).dataList) {
    (window as any).dataList.shift();
  }
  sessionStorage.setItem(
    'dataList',
    JSON.stringify((window as any).dataList),
  );
  if ('dataList' in localStorage) {
    let localStorageDataList = JSON.parse(
      localStorage.getItem('dataList') || '[]',
    );
    localStorageDataList = localStorageDataList.filter(
      (item) => item !== data.current,
    );
    localStorage.setItem('dataList', JSON.stringify(localStorageDataList));
  }
};


const callData = () => {
  if (!data.current) {
    data.current = uuid();
  }

  updatedataList(data.current);
  const intervalID = setInterval(() => {
    const localStorageDataList = JSON.parse(
      localStorage.getItem('dataList') || '[]',
    );
    if (localStorageDataList.indexOf(data.current) === 0) {
      clearInterval(intervalID);
      //logic to execute
      removedataList()
    }
  }, 10000);
};
```

Here I need to update the `dataList` in all the storages. It is an array being used as a queue. I have empty all the sessionStorages and localStorage on browser close(whether clicked by user or due to system crash). How can I do this? Any other implementation suggestion is also welcome, if my approach does not work for all the usecases.

Comment: your code is too complicated please shorten or declare interfaces and i will take care of your problem

Comment: Is there a point why you store the dataList in sessionStorage and not in localStorage? dropping the sessionStorage and just using the localStorage would imo. solve all your problems.

Comment: @Thomas The reason that I am using sessionStorage is to remove the values from localStorage on tab reload. So I check if there are any values in sessionStorage and then remove them from localStorage and after that I remove them from sessionStorage.

Comment: @TachibanaShin I pasted the above code because it shows the code for all the scenarios I have listed above. If remove any part, then it will not work for one/some scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon searching online, I came across an idea of taking the time difference between latest and last updated timestamps. Based on that below is the sample code:

```
let intervalId: { current: NodeJS.Timeout | null } =
    useRef(null);

// Start a setInterval that updates the timestamp every second
const updateTimeStampForCurrentIdInLocalStorage = (id) => {
    intervalId.current = setInterval(() => {
      const timestampsObj = getTimerObjectFromLocalStorage();
      const currentTime = new Date();
      timestampsObj[id] = currentTime.getTime();
      localStorage.setItem(
        'timestampsObj',
        JSON.stringify(timestampsObj),
      );
    }, 1000);
  };

const mainFunction = () => {
  const mainProcessIntervalId = setInterval(() => {
    // timestampobj from localstorage.
    const timestampsObj = JSON.parse(
      localStorageRef.current.getItem('timestampsObj') || '{}',
    );
    if (someCondition) {
      clearInterval(mainProcessIntervalId);
      //continue
    } else {
      const idsInTimer = Object.keys(timestampsObj).filter(
        (id) => id !== currentId,
      );
      idsInTimer.forEach((id) => {
        const currentTime = new Date();
        const lastUpdated = new Date(timestampsObj[id]);
        const timeDiff =
          (currentTime.getTime() - lastUpdated.getTime()) / 1000;
        if (timeDiff > thresholdTime) {
          const timestampsObj = getUuidTimerObjectFromLocalStorage();
          if ((timestampsObj.length > 0)) {
            delete timestampsObj[id];
            localStorage.setItem('timestampsObj', JSON.stringify(timestampsObj));
          }
          if (intervalId.current) {
            clearInterval(intervalId.current || 0);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

To remove data on refresh, a function should be called on `onBeforeUnload` event. Main logic is to check for the `timeDiff` between current time and the last updated time of the existing ids and if they are more than a threshold then remove them.

Answer (score 0):

#### About your problem

##### Explanation

We, the browser or the operating system no one knows when the device suddenly shuts down so listening for that event is impossible

##### Solution

so only save to hard disk no matter what the data is in this code i saved a backup of `dataList` data from `session` to `local` with alias `_dataList` and restored restore it on page reload (I can remove `session` but I think you need it to communicate with the server)

```js
const data = useRef('');

const setDatatInLocalStorage = (event?) => {
  if (!event) {
    event = window.event;
  }
  if (event.key == 'dataList') {
    const localStorageDataList = JSON.parse(event.newValue || '[]');
    localStorage.setItem('dataList', JSON.stringify(localStorageDataList));
  }
};

window.addEventListener('storage', setDatatInLocalStorage, {
  once: true,
});

function syncSeasonToLocal() {
  const sessionStorageDataList = JSON.parse(
    sessionStorage.getItem('dataList') || '[]',
  );
  if (sessionStorageDataList.length > 0) {
    let localStorageDataList = JSON.parse(
      localStorage.getItem('dataList') || '[]',
    );
    if (localStorageDataList.length > 0) {
      localStorageDataList = localStorageDataList.filter(
        (data) => !sessionStorageDataList.includes(data),
      );
      localStorage.setItem('dataList', JSON.stringify(localStorageDataList));
    }
  }
  sessionStorage.removeItem('dataList');
};

onload = () => {
  sessionStorage.setItem("dataList", localStorage.getItem("_dataList"))
  syncSeasonToLocal()
}
onbeforeunload
 = syncSeasonToLocal


const updatedataList = (data) => {
  if ((window as any).dataList) {
    (window as any).dataList.push(data);
  } else {
    (window as any).dataList = [data];
  }
  sessionStorage.setItem(
    'dataList',
    JSON.stringify((window as any).dataList),
  );
  localStorage.setItem("_dataList", JSON.stringify((window as any).dataList))
  if (
    'dataList' in localStorage &&
    !isEmpty(localStorage.getItem('dataList'))
  ) {
    const localStorageDataList = JSON.parse(
      localStorage.getItem('dataList') || '[]',
    );
    localStorageDataList.push(data);
    localStorage.setItem('dataList', JSON.stringify(localStorageDataList));
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem('dataList', JSON.stringify([data]));
  }
};

const removedataList = () => {
  if ((window as any).dataList) {
    (window as any).dataList.shift();
  }
  sessionStorage.setItem(
    'dataList',
    JSON.stringify((window as any).dataList),
  );
  localStorage.setItem("_dataList", JSON.stringify((window as any).dataList))
  if ('dataList' in localStorage) {
    let localStorageDataList = JSON.parse(
      localStorage.getItem('dataList') || '[]',
    );
    localStorageDataList = localStorageDataList.filter(
      (item) => item !== data.current,
    );
    localStorage.setItem('dataList', JSON.stringify(localStorageDataList));
  }
};


const callData = () => {
  if (!data.current) {
    data.current = uuid();
  }

  updatedataList(data.current);
  const intervalID = setInterval(() => {
    const localStorageDataList = JSON.parse(
      localStorage.getItem('dataList') || '[]',
    );
    if (localStorageDataList.indexOf(data.current) === 0) {
      clearInterval(intervalID);
      //logic to execute
      removedataList()
    }
  }, 10000);
};
```

---

#### About your code

Yes when i fix it i feel like i'm betraying myself. it has no type and declaration it even uses the global prop in window and you have coerced its value. It's insulting to the people who designed the typescript

Comment: Thanks for the answer! If it works without sessionStorage then that is great. I added it to account for the changes in `syncSeasonToLocal` function above. I might be doing it in a wrong way. Please tell if it is so. I am using prop in window because i need to reset the uuids on tab refresh. sessionStorage is not getting refreshed in chrome.